# Powershell match operator on cmdlet output OR variable name for pipeline output?

Tags: powershell

I have a simple executable that runs, returns a few lines of code.

I need to grab a section of hex out of that line and store it in a variable.

I have something that works, but would like to make it cleaner? or one line?

The output is several lines, I only care about the one with the hex code.
Typical return string

```
Info: Download of filename (0xff77) completed
```

```
$test1 = .\some.exe 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "0x"
$test1 -match "[0-9a-fA-F]{4}"
$test1 = $Matches[0]
```

I tried piping the output of the first line like so

```
$test1 = .\some.exe 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "0x" | -match "[0-9a-fA-F]{4}"
```

Obviously that didnt work, and I cant find much else on a better way to do this.

Is there a way to address the result of the previous pipeline to pass it to the match command?

```
$test1 = .\some.exe 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "0x" | $HiddenPrevPipeVar -match "[0-9a-fA-F]{4}"
```

What I want my $test1 to be equal to is the hex code  `ff77`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) perform the regex matching for you:

```bash
$test1 =
  (.\some.exe 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=0x)[0-9a-f]+').Matches.Value
```

- `Select-String` outputs [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances describing each match, and its `.Matches` property contains a collection of [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instances describing what the regex passed to `-Pattern` matched. The `.Value` property of each such instance contains the matched text.
- While it is possible to use *capture groups* (`(...)`) in the regex and reference what they captured via `.Matches` as well, in this case it is simpler to use a positive look-behind assertion (`(?<=...)`) in order to effectively exclude `0x` from the match reported in `.Value`
- Also note that `Select-String`, like PowerShell in general, is case-*insensitive* by default, so that `[a-f]` in the regex covers both lowercase and uppercase letters.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution. Worked like a charm!

I tried finding other options for Select String, but didnt realize I could enclose the whole expression and then use Matches on it!